# error when trying to download the Newman REST libraries for Eclipse via sbt

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, rest, newman

I have been spending a lot of time trying to get my REST setup up and running with Scala in Eclipse. I am using Eclipse (Luna) with the sbt plugin.

I wanted to try out the newman library to use for HTTP/REST.

I get an error I cant really figure out, and I hope you guys can help me out.

Here is what I have tried:

I downloaded and installed Eclipse(Luna) and sbt.

I made a new scala project and made a build.sbt file that looks like this:

[build sbt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar89h.png)

Then I navigate to the src folder in my terminal and run sbt, once inside sbt I run the update command and get the following output:

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DktVj.png)

At first it looked like a pretty straight forward error, but I have been unable to find anyone else referencing this particular problem with "not found".

It looks like it goes through all the links looking for it but ends up empty handed. I also tried a version 10 and 12 instead of 11, just to see if that helped (it didn't).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, using sbt and build files is still pretty new to me.

Thanks

Comment: I get the same error. I think the instructions at https://github.com/megamsys/newman/blob/develop/README.md must be wrong. But I don't know what the correct resolver to use would be; you will probably need to contact the authors of the library.

Comment: I will try so see if I can contact them. And update this post if I get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Their instructions are indeed incorrect as I found out when I tried them just now. The solution that worked for me was to add:

```
resolvers += "Newman" at "https://dl.bintray.com/megamsys/scala"
```

And change the library dependency to:

```
"io.megam" %% "newman" % "1.3.11"
```

Note the double `%%` in the middle there, to force sbt to look at `https://dl.bintray.com/megamsys/scala/io/megam/newman_2.11/1.3.11/` which does contain the `newman_2.11-1.3.11.pom` it needs, whereas the `newman` folder doesn't contain anything useful.

In theory, changing `Resolver.bintrayRepo("io.megam", "scala")` in the original instructions to `Resolver.bintrayRepo("megamsys", "scala")` instead of specifying the path the way I did should work, but it didn't work for me when I tried it and now I have the library and all the world it imported in my local cache, everything is hunky dory whatever I do so I can't test it again.